# chatter feed in visualforce replicating 'what i follow'

Tags: chatter

I am using  to display a feed on a custom visualforce page. I would like it to replicate the default chatter behavior when the 'What I follow' tab is selected. See Image.[image]

What do I need to put into the entity id?

```
<chatter:feed showPublisher="true" rendered="true" entityId="WHAT I FOLLOW???">
        </chatter:feed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `<chatter:newsfeed>` component instead to replicate "What I Follow".  See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_newsfeed.htm